# Reassigning Lists in For Loops (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, k-means

Apologies if this has been asked before - I couldn't find what I was looking for after a search, but I'm a beginner, so I might have missed something.

I am trying to implement Lloyd's algorithm in JavaScript (very crudely) to get some practice.

```
var k_means = function (array,number_clusters,max_loops) {
  var initial_centers = underscore.sample(shelter_lat_lon,number_clusters);
  var current_centers = initial_centers;

  var current_associations = {};
  for (p = 0; p < current_centers.length; p++) {
      current_associations[current_centers[p]] = []
  }

  for (loops = 0; loops < max_loops; loops++) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var current_loc = array[i]
      temp_array = new Array();
      for (j = 0; j < current_centers.length; j++) {
        var distance_from_center = distance(current_centers[j],current_loc)
        temp_array.push(distance_from_center)
      }
      var closest_center_lat_lon = current_centers[smallest_index(temp_array)]
      current_associations[closest_center_lat_lon].push(current_loc)
    }
    new_clusters_temp = []
    for (var key in current_associations) {
      lat = []
      lon = []
      for (i = 0; i < current_associations[key].length; i++){
        lat.push(current_associations[key][i][0])
        lon.push(current_associations[key][i][1])
      }
      mean_lat = math_module.mean(lat)
      mean_lon = math_module.mean(lon)
      new_clusters_temp.push([mean_lat,mean_lon])
    }
    current_centers = new_clusters_temp;
  }
}
```

Sorry for the ugly code. There are 2 module requirements - underscore and mathjs (mathjs is called math_module). Additionally, the function distance returns the Euclidean distance (I'm using 2 dimensional data), and smallest_index returns the index of the smallest element in an array.

The only problem I'm having is coming at the line

```
current_centers = new_clusters_temp;
```

Node returns the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined." After debugging a bit, it essentially thinks the array "current_centers" is empty. In Python, this is how I would reassign a list outside of a for loop. Is this different in JavaScript?

Cheers!
Alex

Comment: first thing you need to do is fix your for loops.  for( u = 0; u < something; ++), this syntax makes u a global variable in javascript. You will want to change all of those to for(var u = 0 ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip - changed on my local copy.